# Working with Panolens.js not loading image

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am working with [Panolens.js](https://pchen66.github.io/Panolens/) to get a basic 3d image viewer up and running. I am working off the example provided in the documentation, but I am having console errors when loading. This is my first time working with equirectangular photography and Panolens/ThreeJS.

I have included the code:

```js
var panorama, viewer;

panorama = new PANOLENS.ImagePanorama('http://via.placeholder.com/720x360');

viewer = new PANOLENS.Viewer({
  output: 'console'
});
viewer.add(panorama);
```

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #000;
}

a:link,
a:visited {
  color: #bdc3c7;
}

.credit {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://pchen66.github.io/js/three/three.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://pchen66.github.io/js/panolens/panolens.min.js"></script>
<div class="credit"><a href="https://github.com/pchen66/panolens.js">Panolens.js</a> image panorama example. Image from <a href="http://adaptivesamples.com/tag/equirectangular/">Adaptive Samples</a></div>
```

The console is giving me this error message:

```
Failed to load file:///Volumes/Nifty/DoVR%20Media/demo_v1/test.jpg: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

The image I am using is in the same directory. I also tried loading the image from imgur, but that is also giving me an error.

Comment: You need a server. Use Apache or nginx, or the built-in ones that come with WebStorm / Netbeans, whatever you happen to have handy.

Comment: To be honest, I don't have to much server experience.. can you point me some reading material?

Comment: Are you using a Mac or Windows? Linux? Are you using an IDE like Netbeans or VS Code to write the website code?

Comment: I'm working on a Mac, and using Atom. I know, such a noob :/ I have Eclipse Neon for Java.

Comment: Here you go: http://osxdaily.com/2012/09/02/start-apache-web-server-mac-os-x/

Comment: Thank you very much. Getting through this now!

Comment: You can also use this: https://atom.io/packages/atom-live-server

Comment: Got it working through Atom. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

The reason why you got this error is that you open your index.html page as a local page in browser. In address bar you could see **file://path_to_your_file**.

Some useful details are described in this [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10752055/cross-origin-requests-are-only-supported-for-http-error-when-loading-a-local)

To avoid this error you should launch some web-server. For example if you have installed python you could launch simple web-server which is embedded in it. Also see details in the issue above.

Another alternative to install [VSCode](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) and install [Live Server extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer). Then open folder by VSCode and click on Go Live button.[image]
[image]

As you could see I launch your code in VSCode with LiveServer and all is working.

Answer (score 0):

If the panorama image which you included is on other server then the server should be secure with SSL(https).
You have to change http to https: 
https://via.placeholder.com/720x360